# Which combination of tags should I use?

Tags: html, coding-style

In my form I have 3 styles of text: styleA (size 16 and bold, more like a header) styleB (size 16, normal weight, the normal text) and styleC (size 14 and italic, a note at the end).

Should styleA and styleB use `<h?>` tags and styleC use a `<p>` tag? Or should styleA use an `<h?>` tag, styleB use a `<p>` tag, and styleC use a `<small>` tag? Or is there some other combination I should use?

I'm trying to figure out what the accepted norm is in a situation like this so that I use the correct html in this case and in future, similar cases.

Thank you!

Edit: Just to clarify, all this text will be in a form in an (AJAX) pop-up window. All the text will be within a `<form>` tag. Therefore, I'd prefer to avoid any body/div tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just off the top of my head here...

**HTML 4 or XHTML 1**

- `styleA` should be a heading, probably a level 1 `<h1>` or level 2 `<h2>` heading depending on the nature of the content it encompasses (an article, or the whole page?).
- `styleB` should definitely be a series of `<p>` elements containing your actual content.
- `styleC` could be a specially-designated paragraph. Some examples of how to do this include `<p><small>` or `<p><cite>` or `<p class="footnote">`.

**HTML5 (in case you'd like to try it out)**

- `styleA` should be a heading in a `<header>`.
- `styleB` should be a series of `<p>` elements in a `<section>`.
- `styleC` would do well as a `<p>` in a `<footer>`.

Comment: Just to add: All headings in a page should also make up a hierarchy - meaning that a h2 with no h1 "makes no sense". Same way with a h3 with no h3 present. Creating a hierarchial structure like this provides a proper document outline, and is AFAIK useful to search engines.

Comment: Good semantic markup also helps screen readers determine the structure of documents (accessibility).

Comment: I don't agree with these tag choices if, as stated, "… all this text will be in a form in an (AJAX) pop-up window. All the text will be within a <form> tag." Semantically, label/legend/fieldset tags are more appropriate for sectioning, titling, and labelling form content.

Answer (score 3):

- If it's a header, assign it to one of h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 depending on what you need.
- Standard text can be in either body,p,li,a,div,span.
- Emphasis/bolding/notes can be applied in em,i,b,small,sup,sub

The idea is you want the classes to represent the usecase. So if you're using a class for header text, pair it with a header tag.

Comment: standard text should go to a block level element instead of directly to the body

Answer (score 2):

I would go

- `<h1>` for styleA
- `<p>` for styleB
- `<small>` for styleC

From what you describe, the tag reflects how the text in them are being used, although I might consider `<cite>` for styleC, since `<small>` is more of a visual description, rather than semantic description, like `<cite>`.  (I had thought there was a specific tag for footnotes, but I guess I was thinking of `<tfoot>`)

Comment: Is small a commonly used, accepted tag? I don't think I've ever used it before; I've stuck to h and p.

Comment: You can use `<small>`, but it should not be used alone: put it in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: There is a block-level tag for the footer section, but not footer text in particular.

Also, I would stick with the small tag unless StyleC is actually a citation and not a footer.

Answer (score 2):

You're rather missing the point of semantic mark-up. You need to look for the underlying reason *why* you're using each of those styles for the various elements of the page. Once you understand that, then you will be able to choose the correct mark-up.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you mentioned it's a form you're designing. I'm surprised no one has mentioned this, but it's important to make use of the [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) tag and [`<fieldset>`/`<legend>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.10) tags if you're wanting to create a properly semantic HTML form.

So, your StyleA might make the most sense as a `<legend>` within a `<fieldset>`, not an `<h1>` tag. Your StyleB, if it describes a control, definitely should be a `<label>`. Take a look at some of the example HTML on the W3C pages I've linked above for information on how to properly use these tags.

The note at the end would be in a `<p>` tag, perhaps with some class. Longer informational notes on the form would be in paragraph tags as well.

Here is [an article from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms) which demonstrates an ordered list technique for controls and proper semantic HTML with label and fieldset tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the follwing CSS to define the `h1` and `p` tags and to create a CSS class `note`:

Style A: `h1 { font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; }`

Style B: `p { font-size: 16px; }`

Style C: `.note { font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; }`